# Read Soap Message using C#

Tags: c#, xml, soap

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Head>
    <h:talkId s:mustknow="1" xmlns:h="urn:schemas-test:testgate:hotel:2012-06">
      sfasfasfasfsfsf</h:talkId>
    </s:Head>
  <s:Body>
    <bookHotelResponse xmlns="urn:schemas-test:testgate:hotel:2012-06" xmlns:d="http://someURL" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <d:bookingReference>123456</d:bookingReference>
      <d:bookingStatus>successful</d:bookingStatus>
      <d:price xmlns:p="moreURL">
        <d:total>105</d:total>
      </d:price>
    </bookHotelResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I am trying to read the above soap message `XmlDocument` using C#:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(soapmessage);  //loading soap message as string
XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);

manager.AddNamespace("d", "http://someURL");

XmlNodeList xnList = document.SelectNodes("//bookHotelResponse", manager);
int nodes = xnList.Count;

foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    Status = xn["d:bookingStatus"].InnerText;
}
```

The count is always zero and it is not reading the bookingstatus values.

Comment: Please fix the formatting, especially of the XML message (much of which is missing at present).

Comment: the xml is invalid...b is an undefined namespace..is it d

Comment: @anirudha Meaning, b:total should be d:total in the xml sample

Comment: and the </h:talkidId> doesn't match the <h:talkId>. Off by one error on the number of "id"'s.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`BookHotelResponse` is in the namespace `urn:schemas-test:testgate:hotel:2012-06` (the default namespace in the sample xml) so you need to provide that namespace in your queries:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument(); 
document.LoadXml(soapmessage);  //loading soap message as string 
XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable); 

manager.AddNamespace("d", "http://someURL"); 
manager.AddNamespace("bhr", "urn:schemas-test:testgate:hotel:2012-06"); 

XmlNodeList xnList = document.SelectNodes("//bhr:bookHotelResponse", manager); 
int nodes = xnList.Count; 

foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList) 
{ 
    Status = xn["d:bookingStatus"].InnerText; 
}
```

Comment: Worked for me once I replaced the 'b:' namespace id typo and changed </h:talkidId> to </h:talkId> in your example xml. Are you sure that the xml in your soapmessage matches the format in your example?

Answer (score 3):

Use `LINQ2XML`

To read bookingStatus,do this

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load("yourStream.xml");
XNamespace s = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";//Envelop namespace s
XNamespace bhr="urn:schemas-test:testgate:hotel:2012-06";//bookHotelResponse namespace
XNamespace d="http://someURL";//d namespace

foreach (var itm in doc.Descendants(s + "Body").Descendants(bhr+"bookHotelResponse"))
{
itm.Element(d+"bookingStatus").Value;//your bookingStatus value
}
```

LINQ2XML is **cool** though....:)

Answer (score 2):

First you want to create a class to deseralize the xml values into

```
    public class bookHotelResponse {
      public int bookingReference { get; set; }
      public int bookingStatus { get; set; }
   }
```

Then you can utilize `GetElementsByTagName` to extract the body of the soap request and deseralize the request string into an object.

```
    private static T DeserializeInnerSoapObject<T>(string soapResponse)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(soapResponse);

        var soapBody = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("soap:Body")[0];
        string innerObject = soapBody.InnerXml;

        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(innerObject))
        {
            return (T)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to get response from soap service. If so, you don't have to do all this hard work (making call, parsing xml, selecting nodes to get the response value) by yourself... instead you need to Add Service Reference to your project and it will do all the rest work for you, including generating class, making asmx call and so on...
Read more about it here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx

Everything you'll need to do after adding reference is to invoke a class method something like this

```
var latestRates = (new GateSoapClient())?.ExchangeRatesLatest();
return latestRates?.Rates;
```