# How to access specific XML element with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm working with an API that is XML only and it's been ages since I've done anything with XML.

The response is below.

How do I get the value of `<status>`.   I tried doing this:

```
XmlNodeList results = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("ProcessRequestResult");
```

But I just end up with InnerText full of XML that I can't figure out how to parse correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<ProcessRequestResponse>
<ProcessRequestResult>
    <ConsumerAddEntryResponse>
          <Status>Failed</Status>
```

Comment: If all you want to do is get the value you should be able to use `xmlDoc.Decendants("Status")` in a `foreach` loop.

Comment: I don't see "descendants" as a method in XmlDocument.

Comment: Didn't realize you were using XmlDocument and not XDocument, disregard my previous comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using Linq To Xml?

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml); //OR XDocument.Load(filename)
string status = xDoc.Descendants("Status").First().Value;
```

**EDIT**

The xml I used to test

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
            <soap:Body>
                <ProcessRequestResponse>
                    <ProcessRequestResult>
                        <ConsumerAddEntryResponse>
                                <Status>Failed</Status>
                        </ConsumerAddEntryResponse>
                    </ProcessRequestResult>
                </ProcessRequestResponse>
            </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>";
```

**EDIT 2**

```
 string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
            <soap:Body>
                <ProcessRequestResponse xmlns=""http://submission.api.domain/"">
                    <ProcessRequestResult>
                        <ConsumerAddEntryResponse>
                                <Status>Failed</Status>
                        </ConsumerAddEntryResponse>
                    </ProcessRequestResult>
                </ProcessRequestResponse>
            </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>";

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace ns = "http://submission.api.domain/";
string status = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "Status").First().Value;
```

Comment: This is what I would have done, Jack uses XmlDocument though.

Comment: @HjalmarZ because *`it's been ages since I've done anything with XML`* ;)

Comment: None of these options are working which is leading me to believe their XML being returned is wrong.

Comment: @JackMarchetti the xml you have posted misses many closing tags, I appended them to the xml and then run above code. It worked of course. See the updated answer.

Comment: Why would their XML be replacing "<" and ">" like this: &lt;ConsumerAddEntryResponse&gt;&lt;Status&gt; ?

Comment: @JackMarchetti I don't know how you get this xml, but most probably it is embeded in another xml(or html), so `<` and `>` are escaped. Try this `var decoded = WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&lt;ConsumerAddEntryResponse&gt;&lt;Status&gt;");` it will give you `<ConsumerAddEntryResponse><Status>`

Comment: Weird. there was an xmlns like this: " <ProcessRequestResponse xmlns=""http://submission.api.domain/"  -- Once I took that out it allw orked.

Comment: @JackMarchetti But you haven't posted that important thing in your question. It would require handle xml namespaces.

Comment: I didn't think that was important. How would I handle the namespace?

Comment: @JackMarchetti I was expecting that question :) see the edit2

Answer (score 4):

Load your xml with [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) and fetch the desired node with [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115.aspx). (I did not test the line but it would look like this)

The document loading process :

```
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load("someXmlFile.xml");
```

The node(s) loading process :

```
//Single node would be :
XmlNode xNode = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//ConsumerAddEntryResponse/Status");

//More than 1 node would be :
XmlNodeList xNodes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//ConsumerAddEntryResponse/Status");
```

Comment: Tried that. xnode is null.

Comment: @JackMarchetti I changed it. Try it like this

Comment: Still null. any other ideas?

Comment: Well it should not be. Have you checked if your xm l document is null first?

Comment: Yeah my XMLDoc is definitely not null. I think the XML they're sending back isn't properly formatted as if I do an XMLVisualize on the InnerXml from the xmldoc the "nodes" don't seem to line up.

Comment: Yeah if your xml is not in a valid format it wont work for sure. You should format it properly just for testing purpose. Then you'll know for sure why it does not work and you'll know if the xpath works too!

Comment: because of this line: <ProcessRequestResponse xmlns=""http://submission.api.domain/""> you need a namespacemanager tied to the doc and namespaces in your xpath statements. See this answer fo an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201822/read-soap-message-using-c-sharp/12202020#12202020

Answer (score 0):

Also, it's possible to use LINQ2XML

```
var s = "<ProcessRequestResponse.....";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(s);
string value = doc.Element("ProcessRequestResponse")
.Element("ProcessRequestResult")
.Element("ConsumerAddEntryResponse")
.Element("Status")
.Value;
```

Comment: But OP's xml start with `soap:Envelope` and `soap:Body`. Not with `ProcessRequestResponse`

Comment: It does not matter. it's just example.