# Extraction of Values from Xml SOAP response in C#

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I am trying to write down a code to read a SOAP Response message and extract values without success.

I am trying to extract scalar values starting at the "structure" node.

Here is my code:

```
        //Extracting the xml http message.

        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlHttp.responseText);

        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);

        nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://messages.ara.algorithmics.com");

        nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns2", "http://ws.ara.algorithmics.com");            

        XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;

        XmlNode root1 = root.SelectSingleNode("//structure", nsmgr);
```

The message is looking like this:

```
            <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
            <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <S:Body>
            <getStructureStatelessResponse xmlns="http://ws.ara.algorithmics.com" xmlns:ns2="http://messages.ara.algorithmics.com">
            <contextId>Interactive_CWMAdmin20140828134101_BASE</contextId>
            <userId>CWMAdminSimulation_10267</userId>
            <parameters>
                <aggregation>a:flat</aggregation>
                <currency>c:usd</currency>
                <depth>2</depth>
                <path requestedValue="portfolio://All%20Portfolios/GROUP">portfolio://actual/GROUP</path>
            </parameters>
            <outputDefs>
                <outputDef definitionId="od0">
                    <outputId>o:Price</outputId>
                    <annualized>false</annualized>
                    <currency>c:usd</currency>
                    <nominalfx>false</nominalfx>
                </outputDef>
                <outputDef definitionId="od1">
                <outputId>o:Value</outputId>
                <annualized>false</annualized>
                <currency>c:usd</currency>
                <nominalfx>false</nominalfx>
                </outputDef>
                <outputDef definitionId="od2">
                <outputId>o:UnitDirtyPrice</outputId>
                <annualized>false</annualized>
                <currency>c:usd</currency>
                <nominalfx>false</nominalfx>
                </outputDef>
            </outputDefs>
            <structure>
                <port childCount="316" expandedNodeName="Position View" name="Position View" nodeId="669">
            <outputResults>
                <scalar ref="od0" value="1.890480805674964E7"/>
                <scalar ref="od1" value="1.890480805674964E7"/>
            <ratio ref="od2" value="NaN"/></outputResults>
            <pos locked="true" name="CF_IF Asset@SPL_ASE@Annuitant mortality improves" nodeId="347" secId="CF_IF Asset@SPL_ASE@Annuitant mortality improves">
            <outputResults>
            <scalar ref="od0" value="0.0"/><scalar ref="od1" value="0.0"/>
            <ratio ref="od2" value="0.0"/></outputResults>
            </pos>
            <pos locked="true" name="CF_IF Asset@SPL_ASE@Assured lives mortality increases" nodeId="359" secId="CF_IF Asset@SPL_ASE@Assured lives mortality increases">
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Comment: Instead of using `XmlElement` have you looked at using `XmlNodeList` something like this perhaps 
`XmlNodeList xnList = document.SelectNodes("//ns2:getStructureStatelessResponse", nsmgr); ` then after that do a foreach(XmlNode xnode in xnList) then look for the inner text of what ever node you are searching..?

Comment: here is a `SO` previousposting you can use as a reference guide as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201822/read-soap-message-using-c-sharp

Comment: I actually used 
            XmlNodeList xnList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ns2:getStructureStatelessResponse/ns2:structure", nsmgr); to get to the "structure" node... My list only shows one element, is that right ? . But from there, I need to extract value from each node below. I tried to use   xnode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name").InnerText; to extract value for the current node, but it does not work.

Comment: Hi, Just to let you know I manage to access nodes. Now it is a matter to actually retrieve data in the right order. I will think about it first on my one and comment again if necessary. Thank you again for your tips! Brice