# Parsing SOAP Response into DataSet

Tags: c#, soap

I know there are already a few posts on this subject, but I've been unable to use the answers to figure out what I need.

I've been referencing the following post: [Read Soap Message using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201822/read-soap-message-using-c-sharp)

The following is my modified SOAP response (just to protect private info):

REMOVED SOAP REQUEST

The following is the code I'm using to try to parse this XML:

```
string file = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xmlSource"];
        XmlReader reader;
        reader = XmlReader.Create(file);
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

        XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();

        var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xd.NameTable);
        //nsmgr.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/");
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("xs", "StAc_StuOnTrans");
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("st", "http://tempuri.org/StAc_StuOnTrans.xsd");
        xd.Load(file);

        XmlNodeList xnList = xd.SelectNodes("//StAc_StuOnTrans", nsmgr);
        int nodes = xnList.Count;


        //xd.Load(reader); //soap message
        XmlNode xn = xd.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode c = xn.FirstChild;
        XmlNode result = xn.SelectSingleNode("Student_OnTranscripts");
```

The code seems to be picking up the node structure fine until I get to the last line at which point "result" is interpreting as null.  From the reading I've done it sounds like I've got the wrong namespace, but no matter what I try to add to the NameSpaceManager it always comes back as null.

Can anyone help me out here?  Does anyone have any recommendations on libraries I can use other than the standard .NET ones?

Comment: You don't need to parse SOAP. The framework will do that for you.  Just use the same datatype on both sides.

Comment: Thaks @matt-dot-net.  Can you provide more detail?  So if I'm using the SOAP response example for the time being, which objects/methods in the framework should I call?

Comment: OK... been a while since I've done this.   I've added the service reference to the project.  Now I just need to call the web service from the code.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was add a service reference to my project and then added the following code:

```
 GlobalWeatherSoap request = new GlobalWeatherSoapClient("GlobalWeatherSoap");

        string test = request.GetCitiesByCountry("Canada");

        StringReader str = new StringReader(test);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(str);
```